# Mute icon for html5 video does not work on Chrome or Safari

Tags: javascript, html, video, image, src

I am facing a problem of which I do not understand the origin:
I have a video playing on a website using the `<video>` tag. Client asked to add only a "mute" button in the shape of an icon that changes when clicked.

So i've tried this:
this is the icon i place over the video

```
<img src="mute0.png" id="mutebutton" onclick="javascript:muteUnmute()" />
```

and this is the javascript:

```
var mutebutton = document.getElementById('mutebutton');

function muteUnmute() {
    video.muted = !video.muted;
}
video.onvolumechange = function(e) {
    mutebutton.src = video.muted ? "mute1.png" : "mute0.png";
}
```

This works fine on Firefox and Opera, but the img src does not change in Chrome or in Safari!

I also tried this:

```
video.onvolumechange = function(e) {
    if (video.muted) {
        mutebutton.src = "mute1.png"
    } else {
        mutebutton.src = "mute0.png"
    }
}
```

but still no result.

Does anybody have a clue why Chrome and Safari do not allow me to change the img src in this way? Can you suggest a way to solve this matter?

Thank you!

**Edit:**

**Solved!** this might be useful to someone:

the problem was on the `video.onvolumechange` event, it seems that Chrome and Safari do not understand that

so I've done this and it now works:

```
var mutebutton = document.getElementById('mutebutton');
function muteUnmute() {
    video.muted = !video.muted;
    mutebutton.src = video.muted ? "mute1.png" : "mute0.png";
}
```

Comment: Instead of putting the solution in your question you should create an answer to your own question. Thanks!